# C++: Call inherited member function from global function

Tags: c++, inheritance

Although I program for many years in C, I am currently working on a project in C++ and I need some help. I have the following situation, which I accompany with the shortest example I could come up with. Classes A and B should ideally not be changed. They belong to a simulation framework which should not be bloated with code specific to my project.

Class B is derived from class A and then a number of classes (D1, D2, up to D11 currently) are derived from B. The function finishSpecific() in all these derived classes has a large amount of common code, which I would like to put into the global function finishSpecificCommon(). In this function, I need to call trace(), which records some information to a trace file (I have changed in the example its behavior for simplicity). However, I cannot seem to figure out how to call trace(). The current code gives the folloawing error:

```
example.cc: In function ‘void finishSpecificCommon()’:
example.cc:22:8: error: ‘trace’ was not declared in this scope
  trace() << "Hello world!";
```

I have researched of course similar answers, but there are some differences in my case which hinder me from applying them. Firstly, trace() is protected and not public, as in all examples I have found. Secondly, there are multiple derived classes (D1, D2, ..., D11) instead of a single derived class and finishSpecificCommon() has to be called in all of them.

I have tried unsuccessfully to use friend. Furthermore, I tried passing an object as a parameter to finishSpecificCommon() through which I could call trace(), but got stuck in the type of the object that should be passed.

I would appreciate any suggestions you might have to get me unstuck.

Here is the example code. Compile it with gcc -c example.cc

example.h:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {

 protected:
    virtual void finishSpecific() { };
    std::ostream & trace();
};

class B: public A {

    virtual void finishSpecific() {}
};

namespace D1_NS {

    class D1: public B {
    protected:
        void finishSpecific();
    };

}

namespace D2_NS {

    class D2: public B {
    protected:
        void finishSpecific();
    };

}

void finishSpecificCommon(void);
```

example.cc:

```
#include "example.h"

std::ostream & A::trace()
{
    std::ostream & output = std::cout;

    return output;
}

void D1_NS::D1::finishSpecific()
{
    finishSpecificCommon();
}

void D2_NS::D2::finishSpecific()
{
    finishSpecificCommon();
}

void finishSpecificCommon()
{
    trace() << "Hello world!";
}
```

Comment: You cannot. `trace();` is only visible in class `A`'s and `B`'s scope.

Comment: trace() must be public. Or, finishSpecific... must be friend of A.

Comment: Dear MatthewRock, I tried friend as I already mentioned, but it didn't work. I added the line 'friend void finishSpecificCommon(void);' to class A, but nothing changed. I also tried with 'friend void ::finishSpecificCommon(void);', with the same unsuccessful result.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `trace` is a member of class A. So you must call it within an instance of a class or define it as `static`. Note that you defined it in the protected section, so you couldn't call it from external function unless you define it as a `friend` to that class.

I suppose that you should add `finishSpecificCommon()` to class A so you could use it in any class derived from A.

```
class A {

 protected:
    void finishSpecificCommon();
    virtual void finishSpecific() { };
    std::ostream & trace();
};

...    

void D2_NS::D2::finishSpecific(){
    finishSpecificCommon();
    trace() << "Hello world!";
}
```